# How to align inline elements using text-align property?

Tags: css

I tried applying the property on the container (body here) and it worked.

```
body { text-align: center; }
```

But when I applied the property on the particular element, it failed to align it towards center.

```
span { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `text-align` should be applied to the parent element if you want to align the `span`. The `span` is an inline element, setting `text-align` on it won't have any effect. (On the other hand `<p>` for example is a block element, so the `text-align` can be applied on it.)

So below an example to align a `span`:

```
<div class="parent">
  <span>test</span>
</div>
```

The css for it:

```
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```